# Tensorflow: RC 0.10 3X Slower than 0.9

Tags: tensorflow

I am compiling the current master version from source. If I compile using CUDA 7.5 and CUDNN 4.0 I get the following compilation error:

```
ERROR: /home/rob/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/BUILD:45:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/contrib/rnn:python/ops/_lstm_ops_gpu':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops_gpu.cu.cc':
'/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/cuda_runtime.h'
'/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/host_config.h'
'/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/builtin_types.h'
[etc...]
```

If I compile with CUDNN 5.1, everything compiles and runs but the execution time is roughly 3X longer for a training script I am currently running compared to the same using the 0.9.0 release installed via pip.

I also tried the pip version of 0.10.rc0 (gpu) and saw the same 3X slow down vs. version 0.9.0

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, py 3.4 and a Tesla K40c gpu. Bazel is version 0.3.1

What is the cause of the 3X slow down of ver 0.10.0rc0 and is there any way to regain the prior performance?

Secondarily, how could I eliminate the build errors when using CUDNN 4?

Comment: This sounds like there might be a bug in the 0.10 release candidate. Could you please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) with some information about your training script? Thanks!

Comment: @mrry -- done, [issue 3603](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3603)

Answer (score 1):

The relative slowness of 0.10.0rc0 is a confirmed bug that is being addressed. More information and status can be found in [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3603).